# How to convert an entire column to int in Python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion, typeerror

I want to **convert** my entire **column** to **int**.

I need this to work:

```
df = df[(df.col > 0)  | (df.col < 10)]
```

So I tried it and it says:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

So I tried this:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(int)
```

But I got this:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-1e+31'
```

Then I tried this based on an answer:

```
df['col'] = int(float(df['col']))
```

And it says:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

How can I make it work? Many thanks.

Comment: `pd.to_numeric`?

Comment: string `'-1e+31'` is a float value so you should use `.astype(float)`